# Convert string to string[] in Angular Reactive Form for use in PrimeNG MultiSelect

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am using PrimeNG Multiselect and it expect a array, but my REST use a string with commas.

How I can convert/transform the data directly?

I found use a directive that extend from ControlValueAccessor, but I get this error

`More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute`

And I think a my directive not working with component input, only for native inputs:

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, HostListener, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[string2array]',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() =>String2ArrayDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class String2ArrayDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value']) onInput = (array?: string[]) => {
    const string = array ? array.join(","): null;
    this.onChange(string);
  }
  onChange: any = () => {};

  @HostListener('blur', []) onTouched = () => { };
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  writeValue(string?: string): void {
    const array = string ? string.split(",") : null;
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', array);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
  }

}
```

Comment: try change the "variable" `string` to another name (I think that string is a word reserved)

Comment: I tried it, but it is not change anything